# How to call VBA Function from excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I try to call the function from a cell by typing =MAE() it won't run, always returns a 0. Can someone help guide me? The function below works fine as a sub procedure. It needs to loop through an entire column and calculate the absolute average

```
Function MAE() As Double
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim nRows As Integer
    Dim total As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mean As Double
    total = 0

    ' Count the rows
    With wsData.Range("A2")
        nRows = Range(.Offset(0, 0), .End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End With
    'loop through rows, add to total, select next cell
    Range("A2").Select
    For i = 0 To nRows
        total = total + Abs(ActiveCell.Value)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next i

    MAE = total / (nRows)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rarely have to select or activate cells.  Never select or activate from a UDF.

Use `Application.Volatile` so that your function will recalculate as values change.

```
Function MAE() As Double
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim rCells As Range
    Application.Volatile
    With wsData.Range("A2")
        Set rCells = Range(.Offset(0, 0), .End(xlDown))
        For Each cell In rCells
            total = total + Abs(cell.value)
        Next cell
    End With

    MAE = total / rCells.Count
End Function
```

This might be more useful.

> MAE(A2:A7)

```
Function MAE(rCells As Range) As Double
    Dim cell As Object

    Application.Volatile

    For Each cell In rCells
        total = total + Abs(cell.value)
    Next cell

    MAE = total / rCells.Count
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid selecting the cells when looping through them.
With the following code it works for me:

```
...
' Count the rows
With ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    nRows = Range(.Offset(0, 0), .End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End With

'loop through rows, add to total, select next cell
For i = 0 To nRows
    total = total + Abs(ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Value)
Next i
```

...